# if (isset($_POST not working for Internet Explorer

Tags: php, forms

I have a form submit that posts to the same page to delete a picture on the server via php.  There are multiple forms and submits on this page and for some reason it won't work using Internet Explorer.  Works fine with Chrome and Firefox.  After clicking submit the page executes the code in the first if (isset($_POST not the correct one below.

**HTML**

```
<form action="owner.php" method="post" class="registration_form">

 <input type="text" name="album_name" />
 <input type="text" name="album_code" />
 <input type="hidden" name="add_album" value="TRUE" />
 <input type="submit" value="Create Album" />
</form>

<form action="owner.php" method="post" class="registration_form">
  <input type="hidden" name="albumdelete" value="TRUE" />
  <input type="radio" name="album" value="'.$album[$key_Number].'">
  <input type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>

<form action="owner.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" value="true" name="picdelete">
  <input type="hidden" name="picture" value="'+d[o].src+'">
  <input type="submit" value="Delete This Picture" >
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['add_album'])) {
  all of my add album code      
  **********This is the code it runs*****

} else if (isset($_POST['albumdelete'])) {


}else if (isset($_POST['picdelete'])) {

  *********This is the code it should run*********
  Works fine on all browsers I test except IE. Tried multiple computers
}
```

Comment: Do you have any nested forms/incorrectly terminated form closing tags? See if all `<form>` tags have a corresponding `</form>` tag

Comment: isset cant be the problem since its server side scripting and nothing to do with whatever client you use.. before your if(isset.. try to print_r(@$_POST); and see what you get.

Comment: I don't see `name="add_album"` anywhere, only for your `picdelete` So it will go for your `else if` condition because the first condition wasn't met. So, it's not an `IE thing`, it's your code; IF that's all you have. Plus, PHP is serverside, not client-side.

Comment: Funny thing is, for all the crap it gets, IE is (and always has been) more strict on using / rendering invalid HTML

Comment: @Fred-ii- I assume the `add_album` field is defined in one of OP's other *"multiple forms and submits"*. The logic is fine and I'd say Scuzzy has hit the nail on the head in the first comment; IE is very intolerant of bad markup

Comment: Hard to say and unclear on OP's part. When I don't see the "full picture", I then take it for "face value". @Phil am also questioning `value="'+d[o].src+'"` - And yes, I believe you're right. OP needs to show full code.

Comment: I've always been a bad shot at shooting black balls at midnight, aiming for a black hole, while at a golf course in the middle of nowhere. Show your full code, or forever hold your peace. Voted to close and won't retract until you do.

Comment: editing for full code and yes all </form> are present.  value="'+d[0].src+'" is part of my ajax to tell it what picture is being deleted. Nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: I found the answer here: https://wpza.net/post-submit-button-not-working-on-edge-or-ie/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using isset($_POST['submit']) to check if a form has been posted or submitted is bad practice because it is not compatible with Internet Explorer.

This method relies on the submit button of the form being present in the $_POST array. The problem is Internet Explorer does not send the submit button as a post variable if the user pressed the enter key to submit the form.

Here is a typical example:

PHP Code

```
<?php 

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    { 
        // a form was submitted (POSTED) 
    } 

?>
```

I see this all the time even with intermediate and above programmers. Perhaps the problem is with many poor quality or out of date online PHP tutorials that are available.

If you are relying on this method and the user used the enter key to submit the form then most likely what would happen is the page would appear to simply refresh. Obviously this could be very frustrating for the user, particularly if it was a long form. This is an accessibility failure, users should always be able to use the enter key to submit forms. An example is a special browser that caters for disabled users who are not able to use a mouse, or a user with any browser without a mouse.

**The solution**

The best practice for checking if a form is submitted is to use the server variable REQUEST_METHOD. This variable will be set to POST if a form was submitted (providing the form had a method of POST. Below is the best practice for detecting form submission with PHP.

PHP Code

```
<?php 

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
    { 
        // a form was submitted (POSTED) 
    } 

?>
```

The above works on all browsers because it is not reliant on the submit button being present in the post variables.

Comment: Can this be modified to know which form was posted?  Perhaps if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == '$POST[form_name]')  ?????

Comment: In **if** condition we are checking for request method! Try printing value of $POST variable to check the contents inside **if** condition.

Comment: The problem with my situation was my form was being set inside of a script. I moved the <form action="owner.php" method="post"> and the </form> outside of the <div> where I called my script that had my form information.  Now I.E. is happy and so am I.  Thanks for the help and pointing me in the right direction