# Compatibility issues in website functionality

Tags: php, html, authentication

I have a basic login system, It all works perfectly when I test it on a Mac, but when any of my windows users try and login, they either get redirected to another part of the login system thats not even linked in any way to where they came from, or they just get a white screen.

My PHP is. 
auth.php

```
<?php session_start(); /* Starts the session */

/* Check Login form submitted */    
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    /* Define username and associated password array */
    $logins = array('ozzie' => 'savox555','devjacob' => '59NassauRoad','builer' => 'xntbuilderd');

    /* Check and assign submitted Username and Password to new variable     */
    $Username = isset($_POST['Username']) ? $_POST['Username'] : '';
    $Password = isset($_POST['Password']) ? $_POST['Password'] : '';

      /* Check Username and Password existence in defined array */      
      if (isset($logins[$Username]) && $logins[$Username] == $Password){
        /* Success: Set session variables and redirect to Protected */
        $_SESSION['UserData']['Username']=$logins[$Username];
        header("location:/upload/index.php");
        exit;
    } else {
        /*Unsuccessful attempt: Set error message */
        $msg="<span style='color:red'>Invalid Login Details</span>";
    }
}
?>
```

My form is: 
     
    
    
    
    Login

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">




</head>

 <body>

 <body class="align">

 <div class="site__container">

 <div class="grid__container">

  <form action="http://xeonnetwork.net/upload/dev/auth.php"       method="post" class="form form--login"> 
                    <h2>Awww snap! Please login!</h2>
    <div class="form__field">
      <label class="fontawesome-user" for="login__username"><span class="hidden">Username</span></label>
      <input name="Username" type="text" class="form__input" placeholder="Username" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form__field">
      <label class="fontawesome-lock" for="login__password"><span class="hidden">Password</span></label>
      <input name="Password" type="password" class="form__input" placeholder="Password" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form__field">
      <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Sign In">
    </div>

  </form>


 </div>

 </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware this is not the most secure way of doing it, I am still learning PHP.

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Do you mean to comapre a username against a password? `$logins[$Username] == $Password)`

Comment: It works, is there any reason it would do what it does on certain browsers?

Comment: No. PHP is server-side and the browser doesn't care.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22004789/if-isset-post-not-working-for-internet-explorer , (var_dump your $_POST to debug upon form submits.)